# 8051 LCD 'Hello World' - replacing DB with variable

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm using a proprietary 8051 board to learn assembly programming. I'm currently working on an LCD 'Hello World' program. Here's the code.

```
lcd_cmd equ 0800h           ;Write COMMAND reg address 0800h
lcd_st  equ 0801h           ;Read STATUS reg address 0801h
lcd_wr  equ 0802h           ;Write DATA reg address 0802h
lcd_rd  equ 0803h           ;Read DATA reg address 0803h

ORG 08100h

hello:  
mov P2, #(lcd_cmd SHR 8)            ;load P2 with high address
mov R0, #(lcd_cmd AND 255)          ;load R0 with command reg addr
mov R7, #03h                        ;set LCD position, line=1, char=3
mov dptr, #mesg1                    ;point to mesg1
acall   wr_string                   ;write mesg1 to LCD

mov R7, #41h                        ;set LCD position, line= 2, char=1
mov dptr, #mesg2                    ;point to mesg2
acall   wr_string                   ;write mesg2 to LCD

stop:   ajmp    stop                ;soft halt  

wr_string:
acall   lcd_busy        ;wait until LCD not busy
mov a, R7                           ;get LCD position
orl a, #080h                        ;msb set for LCD RAM address
movx    @R0, a                      ;write lcd_cmd to set line & char
nxt_char:
acall   lcd_busy                    ;wait until LCD not busy
clr a
movc    a, @a+dptr          
inc dptr                            ;point to next byte in string
jz  str_end                         ;if 0 then end of string

mov R1, #(lcd_wr AND 255)           ;Load R1 with wr_data address
movx    @R1, a                      ;Write char to LCD
sjmp    nxt_char                    ;get next char in string
str_end:    ret

lcd_busy:
mov R1, #(lcd_st AND 255)       ;Load R1 with status address
movx    a, @R1                          ;read LCD status
jb  acc.7, lcd_busy         ;keep checking until busy bit clear
ret

mesg1:  db  "Hello   ",0
mesg2:  db  "World ",0
END
```

Everything works fine. However, I'm having trouble outputting a variable to the LCD. Replacing #mesg1 with a hex value (ascii to keep things simple) simply brings up scrambled characters on the screen. So does calling a subroutine which simply increments a value every time, so I'm unsure what format the data should be when it's moved into the dptr.

Anything stupid I've missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dptr` contains the `address` of the text to display. So, if you replace `#mesg1` with something like

```
mov dptr, #045h
```

you are outputting the (random) contents from memory at address 0x45, which explains the scrambled characters you see.

In order to output some decimal value, you need to convert it to an ascii string first, then you can use your existing `wr_string` routine to get it printed. See http://www.electro-tech-online.com/microcontrollers/14371-hex-decimal-then-ascii.html for a code sample (i,j,k contains the result string which you still need to zero-terminate for your wr_string routine).

---

The following code shows a similar routine.
Note that `wr_string` needs to be modified to read the data from XDATA, not from code memory (`movx a, @dptr` instead of `clr a` / `movc    a, @a+dptr`):

```
    ORG     08100h

hello:
    mov     r7, #42        ; value to convert
    mov     dptr, #buffer  ; destination buffer
    acall   str2ascii      ; convert value

    mov     P2, #(lcd_cmd SHR 8)   ; load P2 with high address
    mov     R0, #(lcd_cmd AND 255) ; load R0 with command reg addr
    mov     R7, #03h        ; set LCD position, line=1, char=3
    mov     dptr, #buffer   ; point to buffer
    acall   wr_string       ; write buffer to LCD

...

str2ascii:
; Converts a one byte decimal value into its ASCII string representation.
; Result is prepended with leading zeroes.
; 0   becomes "000"
; 42  becomes "042"
; 255 becomes "255"
;
; @param r7    Input value to convert (1 byte, 0 .. 255)
; @param dptr  Destination buffer, at 4 bytes (3 digits plus \0)
;
    mov     a, r7
    mov     b, #100
    div     ab        ; leftmost digit in a
    add     a,#30h    ; convert to ASCII
    movx    @dptr, a
    inc     dptr

    mov     a,b       ; get reminder
    mov     b,#10
    div     ab        ; middle digit in a, rightmost digit in b
    add     a,#30h    ; convert to ASCII
    movx    @dptr, a
    inc     dptr

    mov     a,b
    add     a,#30h    ; convert to ASCII
    movx    @dptr,a
    inc     dptr

    mov     a,#0
    movx    @dptr, a  ; terminate string
    ret

    xseg
buffer:     ds 17     ; one LCD line plus terminating \0

    end
```

Comment: Thanks, the first bit makes perfect sense now.

However, I'm struggling to understand which register the data should be in so that wr_string can output it. Acc?

Comment: I have added a code sample (did not have an 8051 environment available earlier and did not want to post unverified code :-) ) The code assumes that your board contains some external memory. The (decimal) data needs to be in r7 in order to be converted. `wr_string` still reads from @dptr, but needs to be changed to read from XDATA (not necessary if xdata is identical to code ram, but this depends on your board). BTW: I was using this IDE, which includes an 8051 simulator: http://mcu8051ide.sourceforge.net, just in case you are still looking for one ...

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! I don't currently have access to the board to test it, but I think I can work out what's going on now.

Answer (score 0):

On your code, dptr contains the address of your code memory which has the string you want to output. So, if you change #mesg1 to some hex value, like this:

```
mov dptr, #mesg1
```

LCD will try to write the ascii value which is on this hex address. And you don't know what it contains. In order to output variables on LCD (just like registers values), you should be attempted to:

1 - You can't store variable data on program memory with DB instruction. It doesn't work. You should write your variable value on internal or external data memory. For example, you can't do this:

```
   MOV dptr, #mesg1                    ;point to mesg1
   ACALL   wr_string                   ;write mesg1 to LCD

;LOTS OF INSTRUCTIONS...

mesg1:
   DB 'MY STRING'            
   DB R1                               ;In case that R1 is your variable
```

In above example, LCD will only output MY STRING, independently the value of R1

2 - You need to convert the value of your variable (which will be on binary, decimal or hexadecimal) to ASCII. Just for 0 to 9, this is a very easy task. Just add to your variable the hexadecimal value 30H. So, for example:

```
    mov R1, #9H               ;in case that R1 is your variable with some number
    MOV A, R1
    ADD A, #30H
    MOV R1, A                 ;R1 will store #39H, which is the ascii value for number 9
```

Thus, an option is to split your variable into individual decimal numbers, and then convert to ascii every one. The [code here](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/microcontrollers/14371-hex-decimal-then-ascii.html) do this, and stores each ascii value on variables i, j, k.

What I used to, is to use two functions: one for read strings from code memory, which was previously stored by DB instruction, and another to read variables values from internal memory:

```
    lcd_port EQU P1               ;The port that I send data to LCD
    data EQU #41H                 ;Some random register in internal data memory

    MOV DPTR, #my_string       
    ACALL lcd_string              ;This function will write on LCD some string

    MOV A, R1                     ;In case that R1 is my variable
    MOV data, A
    ACALL lcd_dta                 ;Writes R1 value on LCD

lcd_string:
    MOV A, #0x00
    MOVC A, @A+DPTR      
    JZ end_lcd_string    
    MOV DATA, A          
    CALL lcd_data        
    INC DPTR             
    JMP lcd_string       
end_lcd_string:        
    RET

lcd_data:
    CALL lcd_busy               ;verify if the LCD is busy, just like your function
    SETB LCD_RS                 ;Set bit on LCD RS pin
    SETB LCD_E                  ;Set bit on LCD Enable pin
    MOV lcd_port                ;Move your data to LCD
    CLR LCD_E                   ;Turn LCD Enable pin to 0
    RET

my_string:
    DB 'HELLO WORLD'
```

The above code should output on LCD the string HELLO WORLD, followed by R1 value.