# After initializing 16x2 LCD how to display characters in LCD with 8051?

Tags: assembly, 8051, lcd

I have some trouble with my LCD interfacing program. I know it is working because it works very well with my Arduino Leonardo. I wrote an 8051 assembly program to interface it. However all I get from LCD is just a blinking cursor. I read a lot of tutorials. But I have not found the solution yet. Here is my program. I am waiting for your helps. Thank you.

```
            ORG     0
            ;---------DECLERATIONS---------
EN          EQU     P3.2
RW          EQU     P3.3
RS          EQU     P3.4
BF          EQU     P3.5
DATAP       EQU     P1
CLRDSP      EQU     01H         ;Clear display
RETHM       EQU     02H         ;Return home
LFTSHT      EQU     06H         ;Write to left
DSPCTRL     EQU     0FH         ;Display on, cursor on and blinking
CRSRSFT     EQU     14H         ;Shift cursor
MODE        EQU     38H         ;Two line display, 5x8 chars, 8-bit bus
INITPOS     EQU     80H         ;Set cursor to first position

        SJMP    MAIN
;---------SUBROUTINES---------
SENDCMD:    CLR     RS          ;Select instruction register
        CLR     RW          ;Select write mode
        CLR     EN          ;Prepare for pulse
        MOV     DATAP,A     ;Bring data into data port
        SETB    EN          ;Apply pulse
        CLR     EN
        RET

SENDDATA:   SETB    RS          ;Select data register
        CLR     RW          ;Select write mode
        CLR     EN          ;Prepare for pulse
        MOV     DATAP,A     ;Bring data into data port
        SETB    EN          ;Apply pulse
        CLR     EN
        RET

WAIT:       CLR     RS          ;Select instruction register
        SETB    RW          ;Select read mode
        SETB    BF          ;Set busy flag as input
        CLR     EN          ;Prepare for pulse
        SETB    EN          ;Apply pulse
        CLR     EN
HERE:       JB      BF,HERE     ;Wait for busy flag
        RET

INIT:       CLR     EN

        MOV     A,#MODE
        ACALL   SENDCMD
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#DSPCTRL
        ACALL   SENDCMD
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#LFTSHT
        ACALL   SENDCMD
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#CLRDSP
        ACALL   SENDCMD
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#RETHM
        ACALL   SENDCMD
        ACALL   WAIT
        RET

MAIN:       MOV     P1,#0FFH
        MOV     P3,#0FFH

        ACALL   INIT

        MOV     A,#'H'
        ACALL   SENDDATA
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#'E'
        ACALL   SENDDATA
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#'L'
        ACALL   SENDDATA
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#'L'
        ACALL   SENDDATA
        ACALL   WAIT

        MOV     A,#'O'
        ACALL   SENDDATA
        ACALL   WAIT

INFLOOP:    SJMP    $

        END
```

Comment: Perhaps examining the code in question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14261374/291641 will help.

Comment: Make sure the wiring is correct in terms of levels, that you actually program the correct bits in the code, that you got the timings right. Please specify which LCD you are using along with a link to a datasheet and show your circuit diagram if possible. PS: also check if you get hung up in the `wait` routine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The LCD that I am using is TC1602B-08(R). The datasheet is available in [link](http://www.tinsharp.com/detail/&productId=808bd2c5-58ae-4935-b884-6247ecee4999.html). The circuit diagram is here: [link](http://toliga.0fees.net/lcd.bmp). And my LCD has a 20SPLC780D controller. And its datasheet is here: [link](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/events/em2014/download/znakove%20LCD_radic%20-%20SPLC780D.pdf). I double check the wiring and will check the wait routine for hang up.

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Did the clock speed of the dev board and your circuit change considerably?

Comment: Yes, it could be. Maybe I should also try it with delays but I am not using a dev board. The oscillator frequency of my AT89C4051 is 12MHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I have just found the solution. I added some delays after I checked the busy flag. After that it works like a charm.

Comment: Hmm, not zero odds that you are ignoring an electrical problem.  Check that the outputs are pulled up by a ~10 kilo-ohm resistor.